# PySpark in Azure redirect URI not obvious

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I'm trying to use the Kantata API to collect some data using a PySpark script in a notebook in Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics and I'm struggling to understand what I should be using for a redirect URI in this instance. I'm working with the oauthlib library for the Oauth2 authentication. I suspect the answer is something super obvious and I'm going to feel incredibly silly, but here we are.

Edit:

I had a request to include my code, so I am doing that here:

```
import requests
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql import Row
import os
from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient
client_id = redacted
client = WebApplicationClient(client_id)
authorization_url = 'https://app.mavenlink.com/oauth/authorize'

url = client.prepare_request_uri(
    authorization_url,
    redirect_uri = #whatever this ends up being
)
```

I'm following along with the [docs](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/clients/webapplicationclient.html) and also for [kantata](https://developer.kantata.com/#section/Authentication) (which is the service I'm actually trying to pull data from)

So when I execute the above, I get:

> https://app.mavenlink.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=redacted&redirect_uri=

So then, of course, because I don't have the URI, I don't receive the code back to do anything from this point and am stuck. So, no error message because I didn't run anything because I know I don't have what I need, if that makes sense.

I'm executing this from within a PySpark notebook in Azure Synapse. I've tried spelunking my way through Azure's documentation but nothing useful yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your expected output? any error or blockers? or any code that you have tried for better understanding about your ask?

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this and totally missed the tiny bit of text at the top of the instructions where there was the implication that one might also use a POST request. Now I have a totally different problem, but this is fixed.

Comment: Hey @DrTaylor, how did you fix this problem?  I am getting a similar problem where the URL has https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/auth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XYZ&redirect_uri=ABC

However, when I click it, the URL changes to ABC?error=invalid_request&error_description=Invalid+launch+options%3A+SyntaxError%3A+Unexpected+end+of+JSON+input

I have used the exact similar structure as you - client.prepare_request_uri and passing auth URl and redirect URL